# How can i convert the string to int and count?

Tags: c#, string-conversion

```
public void Save(string path , string fileName , PictureBox pb)                
{
    int framesNumberX = 0;
    int framesNumberY = 0;
    string fn;
    string t = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.name);
    if (File.Exists(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + fileName + "\\" + t + ".txt"))
    {
        try
        {
            string f = Path.Combine(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + fileName);
            File.Delete(f);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not delete file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        } 
        fn = path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + fileName;
    }
    else
    {
        fn = path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + fileName + "\\" + this.name + ".txt";
    }
    OptionsFile setting_file = new OptionsFile(fn);
    setting_file.SetKey("File Name", fn);
    setting_file.SetKey("Object Name", fileName);
    setting_file.SetKey("Animation Name", this.name);
    setting_file.SetKey("picturebox.Width", pb.Width.ToString());
    setting_file.SetKey("picturebox.Height", pb.Height.ToString());
    string[] xFrames = new string[wocl.Count];
    string[] yFrames = new string[wocl.Count];
    string X="";
    string Y="";
    for (int i = 0; i < wocl.Count; i++)
    {
        X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1);
        Y  = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", i + 1);
        int c = Convert.ToInt32(X);
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(Y);
        framesNumberX += c;
        framesNumberY += d;
        for (int j = 0; j < wocl[i].Point_X.Count; j++)
        {
            xFrames[i] += string.Format("{0},", wocl[i].Point_X[j]);
            yFrames[i] += string.Format("{0},", wocl[i].Point_Y[j]);   
        }    
        string tt = xFrames[i].Trim(",".ToCharArray());
        string yy =  yFrames[i].Trim(",".ToCharArray());
        setting_file.SetKey(X, tt);
        setting_file.SetKey(Y, yy);
    }    
    setting_file.SetKey("Number Of Frames X", framesNumberX.ToString());                
}
```

If im doing in the loop for example : FrameNumber +=; it will count me the number of frames for example 6. But i want to count how many times the frames of X showed up and how many frames of Y.

I tried ot it like this:

```
X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1);
Y  = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", i + 1);
int c = Convert.ToInt32(X);
int d = Convert.ToInt32(Y);
framesNumberX += c;
framesNumberY += d;
```

But thats not working not a good way.

Maybe i need to make the counting of X and Y in the end after the variables tt and yy ?
I want to count how many times the loop did the variable tt and how many times it did the variable yy. Just puting int variable and make ++ will give me the overall frames i need to seperate them to X and Y. So if i have for example 6 frames so X will be 3 and Y will be 3.

Comment: This question makes no sense... it is full of rambling and run-on sentences.

Comment: What results are you getting exactly?

Comment: Ramhound i didnt get any results since its impossible to convert the X and Y that way to int. Im getting error illegal character.

Comment: @user1526380 - That means what you are trying to convert isn't a number

Comment: @user1526380 -Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it works for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

for this code to work

```
  X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1);
  Y  = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", i + 1);
  int c = Convert.ToInt32(ExtractNumbers(X));//modfied code line
  int d = Convert.ToInt32(ExtractNumbers(Y));//modfied code line
  framesNumberX += c;  framesNumberY += d;
```

you need to extract number something like this

```
static string ExtractNumbers( string expr )
{
 return string.Join( null,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split( expr, "[^\\d]" ) );
}
```

---

**Prev Ans**

Good way to do is

```
static void Main()
    {
    // Convert string to number.
    string text = "123";
    int num = -1;
      if( int.TryParse (text,out num))
    Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
```

check that string is convertable or not

Comment: @ChrisGessler - Except the author is having a problem, doesn't tell us what result he is getting, and `int.Parse` is a different method then `Convert.Int32()`

Comment: @ChrisGessler, but then again. Is this really the first time OP has stuff in the code which he/she has no idea about?

Comment: @PranayRana - int.Parse would throw an exception if the string is not a number.  Much better to use TryParse in a case like this.

Comment: @Ramhound -yes thanks for poting it out...

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.Int32()` isn't a `Val()` method, in other words, it won't take just the numbers from any string.  When using `Convert.Int32()`, the entire string has to be numeric, for example:

```
// doesn't work
string x = "My string 123";
int y = Convert.Int32(x);

// does work
string x = "123";
int y = Convert.Int32(x);
```

If I understand correctly, you're trying to convert something to an int and count at the same time (here).

```
X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1); 
Y  = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", i + 1); 
// blows up with an exception
int c = Convert.ToInt32(X); 
int d = Convert.ToInt32(Y); 
framesNumberX += c; 
framesNumberY += d;
```

The above could better be written like:

```
X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1); 
Y  = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", i + 1); 

framesNumberX++; 
framesNumberY++;

// or (depending on what you need)
framesNumberX = i + 1;
framesNumberY = i + 1;
```

Or - Which would be even more clear; do your math operation first, then use the result in your `string.Format()` call;

```
framesNumberX = i + 1;
framesNumberY = i + 1;

X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", framesNumberX); 
Y  = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", framesNumberY);
```

However, framesNumberX and framesNumberY would be equal to eachother AND to the iterator `i + 1`.  This is where I'm starting to lose the purpose of the variables.  It would help if you could clarify in pseudo-code what exactly you're trying to accomplish:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   ... code here

   // trying to `your explanation`
   ... code here


    // and here, I'm trying to `your explanation`
    ... code here

}
```